# Unusual Issue with PHP/MYSQL-- Names are getting cut off

Tags: php, url

For certain products in my Database, The name of the product will get cut off between the 
`<a href=" RIGHT HERE   ">  </a>`

It will display correctly via the HTML visual side. But, the link will sometimes render a shortened name.

Does anybody have any idea why this could be?

I cant seem to even think what the problem could be?

```
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                {


        $namelink = str_replace(" ","_",$row[1]);



print <<< PRODUCT_RESULTS
    <table  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" id="vProducts">
        <tr>
                <td><img src="$row[3]"/></td>
                <td id="productTitle"><a href="/view_product1.php?name=$namelink&model=$row[0]">$row[1]</a><br />
                <li>Model: $row[0]</li>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="width:749px; height:1px; background:#CCC;"></div>

PRODUCT_RESULTS;
}
```

Table Structure:

```
   CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `modelNumber` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shortDescription` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `largeImage` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL
  )
```

Comment: Some code and table structure would be nice

Comment: Is this 2011? The mysql extension went out of fashion half a decade ago, use mysqli or PDO both have prepared statements and so you can avoid SQL injection attacks. Using $row[1] will guarantee a place at an obfuscation contest -- use column names for readibility. Finally dumping data like that without escaping into HTML is a particularly good idea too.

Comment: @chx Thanks for your advice. Having been programming for just a short while, I am still learning the game.

Comment: Is it possible you have special characters in your names which need escaping by `urlencode()` before putting them in the URL? Seeing the  output source code would be helpful too.

Comment: @chx Just as a note: There are plenty of servers which do not have the PDO libs installed on them. It is unfortunate but true.

Comment: @cwallenpoole mysqli? also note: Drupal 7 uses PDO and so those sites rule out an extremely popular CMS...

Comment: @chx Look, I'm not saying that I think it is a good idea. Heck, it's downright annoying, but I have run into cases where PHP 5 was available but only basic MySQL functionality. Personally, it actively bothers me that I am the only one at my company who insists on PDO for PHP 5.x stuff...

Comment: @chx Honestly, PDO is God's gift to PHP programmers. I've yet to see another language have something so, frankly, elegant.

Comment: @chx Respectively, you have most likely been programming for quite some time. Stemming from the fact that you have exemplified your involvement in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound crazy, but do you have `>`, `"`, or some other character which would make for invalid HTML in that entry? What happens when you use "view source"? Is it still cut off?

As an aside, I don't know if you realize this, but you're doing a double-lookup on those variables. This is not only slower, but it is harder to debug. Instead of doing this:

```
             <td id="productTitle">
                  <a href="/view_product1.php?name=$namelink&model=$row[0]">
                      $row[1]
                  </a>
                  <br />
                  <li>Model: $row[0]</li>
```

Set variables before the print equivalent to each of the array indexes and then output that result.

You could also get rid of the call to print and simply use `?> <?php`. Obviously, you would need to output the contents of the variables manually once you did that, but it would, arguably, be cleaner and clearer.

Comment: The reason that numerical indexes are used here is that the OP used numerical indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$row[3]` to `$row[image]` and `$row[0]` to `$row[modelNumber]` etc..
And if that didn't work i would need to see the $query.

Edit:
Krinkle (comment below), suggests using `$row["image"]` and `$row["modelNumber"]` which is a better practice.

Comment: Do not change them to `$row[image]` but to `$row["image"]` (notice the quotes), otherwise you'll be referring to global constants.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and yes using quotes is a better -correct- practice as in `$row["image"]`, but i am pretty sure `$row[image]` would function without a problem (will throw a notice though) if it's not used as a constant.